# Source, Target, and Intermediate Way Points

Tags: c#, time, unity-game-engine, distance

1. Consider two points: (0,0,0) as source and (1000,0,0) as target
2. A cube game object wants to travel from source and target at a pre-defined/constant speed. Time taken: t1
3. Introduce 100 **intermediate points** between source and target, i.e. `INTERMEDIATE_POINTS = 10` 
   Example: (0,0,0), **(10,0,0), (20,0,0), (30,0,0).... (980,0,0), (990,0,0)**, (1000,0,0). Same speed, time taken: t2.
4. Introduce 50 **intermediate points**, i.e. `INTERMEDIATE_POINTS = 20` ; (0,0,0), **(20,0,0), (40,0,0),..., (960,0,0), (980,0,0),** (1000,0,0). Same speed, time taken: t3.

**Result**: t1 < t3 < t2, i.e. more intermediate points, more time taken to reach the target (although same path and same speed)

**Question**: If you compare, the game object moves in the same way (same path, same speed) in all the three cases (no intermediates, 100 intermediates, and 50 intermediates) that are mentioned above. But why is there a time difference to reach the target?

**Code to test this scenario:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TestSpeed : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<Vector3> listOfPoints = new List<Vector3>();
    private int INTERMEDIATE_POINTS = 1;

    private int counter = 1;

    private float speed = 50.0f;

    private float originalDistance = 0.0f;
    private float distanceCovered = 0.0f;
    private float overshoot = 0.0f;
    private Vector3 modifiedTarget;

    // for the car movement. 
    private Vector3 targetPosition; // after every loop, get the next position
    private Vector3 currentPosition;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i = i + INTERMEDIATE_POINTS)
        {
            listOfPoints.Add(new Vector3(i, 0, 0));
        }

        currentPosition = this.transform.position; // at the beginning, from (0,0,0) 
        targetPosition = listOfPoints[counter];

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        originalDistance = Vector3.Distance(targetPosition, currentPosition);
        distanceCovered = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, currentPosition);

        if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, new Vector3(0,0,0)) >= 995.0f)
        {
            System.TimeSpan t = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Time.timeSinceLevelLoad);
            string answer = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}",
                    t.Hours,
                    t.Minutes,
                    t.Seconds);
        }

        if ((originalDistance - distanceCovered) <= 0.0f)
        {
            currentPosition = transform.position;
            targetPosition = listOfPoints[counter];
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
            if((distanceCovered + step) >= originalDistance)
            {
                overshoot = distanceCovered + step - originalDistance;
                counter++;
                modifiedTarget = Vector3.Lerp(targetPosition, listOfPoints[counter], (overshoot / originalDistance));
            }
            else
            {
                modifiedTarget = targetPosition;
            }

            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, modifiedTarget, step);
        }
    }
}
```

**How to use the code:**

Just create a cube game object and assign the script to it. Near to `string answer` set a break-point to check the time duration with various number of intermediate points.

Comment: What kind of time scale are we talking here? And are you sure that your code always creates the same total distance? The way you generate your waypoints seems a little goofy.

Comment: Time scale in seconds. For example, t1 = 00:25 t2=00:42 t3=00:38 with 40 FPS. The way points are just an example to illustrate the various time durations. Normally in an application, closer the way points, finer the movement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this logic here is the cause of the strange observation:

```
if ((originalDistance - distanceCovered) == 0.0f)
{
    currentPosition = transform.position;
    targetPosition = listOfPoints[counter];
    counter++;
}
```

You check whether or not you've arrived at your destination waypoint by checking for an *exact* position match; however, the distance you travel per `Update` is anything but exact. That means that your object could very well **overshoot** the destination, then try to move back towards it, overshoot it again, then repeat.

I bet if you watch your cube in the scene view, you'll see it hover around a single waypoint for a bit until it manages to hit the exact distance it needed.

You're probably better off using an inequality here, for example:

```
if ((originalDistance - distanceCovered) <= 0.0f)
{ /* ... */ }
```

Your object has reached its waypoint if the distance it has traveled is greater than or equal to the distance it needed to travel. `originalDistance - distanceCovered` will be negative as soon as the object has reached or passed the waypoint.

EDIT:

```
X.....X.....X.....X.....X.....X
```

Here are some waypoints. Pretend we have an object traveling along the path of waypoints. It starts at the first one on the left and goes right. It'll be represented by an `O`.

```
O.....X.....X.....X.....X.....X
```

Now it moves along for a while. Due to the variability of `Time.deltaTime`, it might move one or two spots each tick. So let's say it winds up here after a few ticks:

```
X....OX.....X.....X.....X.....X
```

And during the next tick, it moves two:

```
X.....XO....X.....X.....X.....X
```

With your original check, the object will now travel *backwards*. It needed to travel a distance of seven spaces, but it traveled 8. So with your original check, `originalDistance - distanceCovered != 0.0f`. So it'll keep trying to hit that spot over and over again until it hits it on the dot.

Even if you introduce the idea of a "threshold", you're still going to have the same problem. There is no fixed distance traveled per tick, so that means that each waypoint will have some artificial "bounce" time unless that threshold is so large that the waypoints become meaningless.

If you use `originalDistance - distanceCovered <= 0.0f`, you will always move on to the next waypoint if it overshoots. Instead of trying to land the object in some small window, you're just making sure that the object has passed or met its waypoint.

Comment: I tried that kind of approach already, i.e. the difference less than 1.0f. Even with your suggestion, there is a difference in time durations, i.e. still doesn't work.

Comment: Would it be ok for you to remove this as an "answer", so that others would take a look at this thread to answer? Thanks!

Comment: Comparing the difference to some arbitrary value doesn't change anything. You need to check if the object has reached or surpassed its goal, not if the object has moved within some small window of the goal. I will update my answer to elaborate.

Comment: I also added the concept of overshoot, i.e. when the object travels 'x' distance more, I save this overshoot point in the next way point. Please refer the modified code in the question section. I don't know why it does not work. Which solution would you suggest me, in order to overcome this problem?